# Custom shortcuts replacing Ctrl+Tab

Tags: shortcut

Its pretty uncomfortable to use Ctrl+TAB to switch between vertex/edge/face selections in edit mode. Is there a way to make custom shortcuts for each of them?

Allso Is there shortcut for sculpt mode? And if not can I create one and how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to File > User Preferences > Input, then expand the 3D View section and the "3D View (Global)" Section. It will look like this:

[image]

Scroll to the bottom and you'll see an "Add New" Button. Click that and expand the new shortcut. It will look like this:

[image]

Type in the command that Blender will need to complete when you enter your shortcut. In your case, that's: `mesh.select_mode`. Then Change the Action to "Enable" and set the keyboard shortcut that you want. In this case, I'll use Alt+Shift+V:

[image]

Repeat these steps for the other 3 selection modes. You can also make a shortcut to toggle sculptmode by using the command: `sculpt.sculptmode_toggle` You can see what these commands are by lowering the info window after you have set the mode to sculpt:

[image]