# Mesh object select shortcuts

Tags: modeling

I was wondering how in Blender 2.8 do you activate the shortcuts for the mesh objects in edit mode. That being 1 for vertex 2 for edge and 3 for face.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W99lFlWrbCk&t=19s
7:25

Thanks so much
Umar

Comment: It should be enabled by default but this should work:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106224/custom-shortcuts-replacing-ctrltab